# Bug.Field method not available in C sharp. But available in VB.net for OTA Client

Tags: .net

I am trying to connect to hpqc and get list of defects and their fields using OTAclient.dll

But when i use C # Code like this

```
Bug TheNewBug ;

    Console.writeln( TheNewBug.Field("sdf"));
```

It does not Compile

But this

```
   Dim TheNewBug As Bug
        Dim abc
        abc = TheNewBug.Field("sdf")
```

Compiles properly.

I am using the same dll for both

I want to know how to use Field property of Bug in C #

Comment: If "It does not Compile", it presumably gives you an error message of some sort. Could you add the error message to your question please?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Field is a collection. In C#, you use square brackets for the parameter to an indexer, in the same way as you would use square brackets for arrays.

So try

```
Console.writeln(TheNewBug.Field["sdf"]);
```

Comment: The problem is , Field method is not available for Bug object in  C # but it is available in VB

Comment: @ind - Are you sure that `Field` is a method?

Comment: Yea i got it
TheNewBug["BG_SEVERITY"] did the trick

Damn you c sharp !  (I come from java background)

Comment: Field is not a method, it's a property, just as you said in your original question. More specifically, it's an indexer, i.e. a parameterized property. Don't be so hard on C#, it's just different from a language you are more familiar with. One of the things I dislike about VB is there is no use of square brackets, so you can't easily pick between arrays/indexers and methods.